# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: rate limit exceeded when loading resnet18 from pytorch hub

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, http-error

I am not sure why I get a rate limit error.

```
(fashcomp) [jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ python main.py --test --l2_embed --resume runs/nondisjoint_l2norm/model_best.pth.tar --datadir ../../../data/fashion
/scratch3/venv/fashcomp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py:310: UserWarning: The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, please use transforms.Resize instead.
  warnings.warn("The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, " +
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 313, in <module>
    main()    
  File "main.py", line 105, in main
    model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v1.9.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
  File "/scratch3/venv/fashcomp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 362, in load
    repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, verbose)
  File "/scratch3/venv/fashcomp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 162, in _get_cache_or_reload
    _validate_not_a_forked_repo(repo_owner, repo_name, branch)
  File "/scratch3/venv/fashcomp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 124, in _validate_not_a_forked_repo
    with urlopen(url) as r:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: rate limit exceeded
```

I have:

```
$ pip freeze
h5py==3.3.0
joblib==1.0.1
numpy==1.21.2
Pillow==8.3.1
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scipy==1.7.1
sklearn==0.0
threadpoolctl==2.2.0
torch==1.9.0
torchaudio==0.9.0
torchvision==0.10.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
```

and I followed this from https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_resnet/ :
[image]

Comment: Try an older version of pytorch or any other suggested fix here https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/4156 ?

Comment: I need to use 1.9.0

Comment: Can you use torchvision.model instead of torch.hub?

Comment: when i did so, I got this error ` Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "embeddingnet.embeddingnet.fc_embed.weight", "embeddingnet.embeddingnet.fc_embed.bias". `

Comment: I think the state you're trying to load might not be the same as the model you're trying to use? Like there might've been different layers?

Comment: thanks for looking, since it felt like a different issue i asked it in a different issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68901648/using-the-torchvision-resnet18-model-instead-of-a-custom-resnet18-module-results

Answer (score 14):

This is a bug in Pytorch 1.9. As a workaround, try adding:

```py
torch.hub._validate_not_a_forked_repo=lambda a,b,c: True
```

to your script before any `torch.hub` call. i.e.:

```py
torch.hub._validate_not_a_forked_repo=lambda a,b,c: True
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.9.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
```

According to Philip Meier(one of the developers)'s [post](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/4156#issuecomment-884660424) , This is a bug introduced in Pytorch 1.9 ([#56138](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/56138)) and you shouldn't be facing this in older versions.
This is already fixed in the master, but whether there is a 1.9.1 to have this shipped with is not known at the moment. So until 1.10 ships, you either have to use an older version or use `torchvision` instead or simply use the [workaround](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/61755#issuecomment-885801511) proposed above.

### Update:

Pytorch released a bugfix for 1.9 (i.e. 1.9.1) so updating to 1.9.1 should rectify this issue for good.