# Unknown errors with setting up a PyTorch Image classifier

Tags: python, tkinter, pytorch, torchvision

As part of a computer science project, I have decided to create an image classifying CNN using PyTorch, which a user can interact with by selecting their image (using Tkinter as a GUI) then the model will run this image through and output the predictions and confidence scores.

To speed up the progress, I have decided to use the ResNet18 model from PyTorch's website as well as [their example code](https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_resnet/) but adapted it into my program. From here, I can gradually add and change things until eventually, I have my hand-trained model.

However, the code is raising many errors when trying to pass the image through the model. I don't expect someone to code the perfect solution for me as it needs to be my work anyway, just an idea as to what the error messages mean and what I need to look at rewriting.

The code is attached below, as well as a transcript of the error messages:

```
import torch, torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile, askopenfilename
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def SelectUserImage():
    userfilewindow = tk.Toplevel()
    path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File", '*.jpg')])
    image = Image.open(path)
    MLImage = image.convert('RGB')
    MLImage.save('MLImage.jpg')
    test = ImageClassifier(MLImage)
    userfilewindow.pack()


def ImageClassifier(MLImage):
    ClassifierWindow = tk.Toplevel()
    model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
    model.eval()
    preprocess = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])
    input_tensor = preprocess(image)
    input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        input_batch = input_batch.to('cuda')
        model.to('cuda')
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_batch)
    # Tensor of shape 1000, with confidence scores over Imagenet's 1000 classes
    print(output[0])
    probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output[0], dim=0)
    print(probabilities)
    with open("imagenet_classes.txt", "r") as f:
        categories = [s.strip() for s in f.readlines()]
    # Show top categories per image
    top5_prob, top5_catid = torch.topk(probabilities, 5)
    for i in range(top5_prob.size(0)):
        print(categories[top5_catid[i]], top5_prob[i].item())
    ImageClassifier.Pack()


window = Tk()
window.title("CS Machine Learning Project")  # Title for the main window
FileExplorerLogo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Local PC Icon.png"))
Button(window, text='Choose Locally Stored Image', image=FileExplorerLogo, command=SelectUserImage, compound=LEFT).pack(
    side=TOP)  # Button to load image from PC
GDriveLogo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Google Drive Icon.png"))
Button(window, text='Choose Image from Google Drive', image=GDriveLogo, compound=LEFT).pack(
    side=TOP)  # Button to load image from Google Drive

window.mainloop()
```

Errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\griff\PycharmProjects\Project_Interface\main.py", line 28, in SelectUserImage
    test = ImageClassifier(MLImage)
  File "C:\Users\griff\PycharmProjects\Project_Interface\main.py", line 35, in ImageClassifier
    model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 362, in load
    repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 162, in _get_cache_or_reload
    _validate_not_a_forked_repo(repo_owner, repo_name, branch)
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 124, in _validate_not_a_forked_repo
    with urlopen(url) as r:
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\griff\miniconda3\envs\PyTorch\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: rate limit exceeded
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68901236/urllib-error-httperror-http-error-403-rate-limit-exceeded-when-loading-resnet1). Can you confirm the version of pytorch ?

Comment: 1.9 I think. I’ll try that fix later. Thank you!